# How to make an app larger than 500M in Heroku?

Tags: docker, heroku

I am trying to create an app in Heroku. I have done different things to make it smaller (now it is shrunk to one third of its original version) and still its "compiled slot size" gets to 760M. So it keeps fail to push since it is larger than 500M.  I am trying to figure out if there is a service that I can pay for the space and let me to push an app larger than 500M. I cannot find which service gives me such option.

I really need to solve this problem, because this is a very basic version of my app and I hope to expand it further to a commercial app.

Comment: Docker images do not have the 500M size limit restriction. You can go the docker route.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tin. It took me a while to figure out how to deploy with the Docker, but your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your slug is very large and you can try to reduce it further (especially if this is supposed to be a simple version of your application).
You can look at which dependencies you import and leave out what you don't really need: how to do it depends on your stack (for Java Maven apps you trim the POM file, Python the requirements.txt, etc..)

Check also out [slugignore](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore) in case you can leave out files and assets from your project folder

A good option is to [dockerize](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker) the application: the Docker images do not have the same slug restrictions.

If all the above is not successful you might need to look at a different provider (DigitalOcean has no slug restrictions but it does not have a free plan) or a change in your architecture (split the application in different components).

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed explanation. The docker solved the problem after some struggles. Thank you.